# Previous and next row in PHP

Tags: php

I have a table in phpmyadmin with a `'val'` column and a `'num'` column. These two columns have numbers ranging from 0 to 10. Using PHP I want to access this table in phpmyadmin and when my 'val' = 10, I want to get the 'num' value that is immediately before and after that 'val' = 10 value. So in the image I want to get when val = 10, the num = 9 and 4, and for the second val = 10, num = 4 and 10.

```
$s = $mysqli->query("SELECT `Num` FROM `user_entries` WHERE `Val` = 10");
```

I wasn't sure what to add next as I haven't found any function that is able to do this. How can I do this?

[image: This is a smaller sample of the table I am using]

Comment: It is easy for your question to be misunderstood, so try to post some more explanation and the expected output with may be some data or pic

Comment: If you want to do this in php, why is the question tagged "sql".  If it is tagged "sql" and you want to do the work in a database, which database are you using?  Also, it helps to have sample data and desired results in the question to clarify it as much as possible.

Comment: Sorry about that, I got mixed up for a bit. I hope this is enough explanation, if not I will try to add more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do this the way your table is (you actually might be able to do so in PHP, but that could work how you want it one day, but not the day after .. (see [this link](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6051/what-is-the-default-order-of-records-for-a-select-statement-in-mysql))).

I would recommend to had a column, `id` or `sort`, depending on what you need, who would look like :

```
id  Val     Num
1   2       6
2   0       0
3   4       8
4   3       9
5   10      1
6   8       4
7   10      6
8   5       10
```

With this, i would recommend using MySQL to get what you want :

```
SELECT 
IFNULL((SELECT f2.Num FROM user_entries f2 WHERE f2.id = f.id-1),-1) AS previous_Val,
IFNULL((SELECT f2.Num FROM user_entries f2 WHERE f2.id = f.id+1),-1) AS next_Val
FROM user_entries f
WHERE Val = 10    
ORDER BY id
```

This would return :

```
previous_Val    next_Val
9               4
4               10
```

In the case there is no previous_Val or next_Val, it would return `-1`.

You might need to see how you can use this, hope it helps.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I get what you are doing, I probably would stuffed that up if I had tried it. But I did add the id column, now how would I print that out? I get that they have returned the desired values, but how do I print out the values of the returned sql statement?

Comment: Now, you only need to fetch your values with something like `while($row = $s->mysqli_fetch_assoc())` and then you can access `$row['previous_Val']` and `$row['next_Val']` for each of your `val = 10` (remember that the order is `id ASC`)

Answer (score 0):

Your Query should be like this

```
"SELECT `Num` FROM `user_entries` WHERE `Val` = '10' ";
```

Comment: Okay I have changed that. I always thought that I had the right syntax, but I guess not. It still doesn't help me try to find the values I need?